# How to set left and right margin for UITableView in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am using *UITableView* inside my controller that displays cells with some informations (title, subtitle and image). I would like to add some padding to the *tableView*, but I can't find the right solution. This is my code for table view:

```
private let tableView: UITableView = {
    let tableView = UITableView(frame: .zero, style: .grouped)
    tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    tableView.backgroundColor = .clear
    tableView.separatorStyle = .none
    tableView.allowsSelection = false
    tableView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
    return tableView
}()
```

Inside *viewDidLoad()* I setup constraints for that *tableView*

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
    tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
    tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
    tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor)
])
```

Right now my view looks like this:

[image]

Now when I try to configure *contentInset* property inside my *tableView* closure by adding this:

```
tableView.contentInset = .init(top: 0, left: 23.5, bottom: 0, right: -23.5)
```

As you can see it only added space on the left side, but looking at the *debug view hierarchy*
I can say that it moved that *contentView* to the right side (It's still have the same width as its superview)
[image]

[image]

Info from view debugger.
*TableView*:

```
<UITableView: 0x7fba82016000; frame = (0 0; 390 844); clipsToBounds = YES; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x60000023de90>; layer = <CALayer: 0x600000c4b9e0>; contentOffset: {-23.333333333333332, -47}; contentSize: {390, 635.66666666666663}; adjustedContentInset: {47, 23.5, 34, -23.5}; dataSource: <Myapp.WelcomeViewController: 0x7fba81c08f60>>
```

and First cell:

```
<UITableViewCellContentView: 0x7fba84021250; frame = (0 0; 390 87); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x6000002cf900>; layer = <CALayer: 0x600000c2b900>>
```

*TableView* has the same width as cell (390 vs 390). How can I add my paddings to the left and right to the *tableView*, without making constraints on that *tableView* (I want that area to also be scrollable)

Comment: Have you tried changing the right inset to 23.5 instead of -23.5?

Comment: @boa_in_samoa I have already tried with tableView.contentInset = .init(top: 0, left: 23.5, bottom: 0, right: 23.5), and with that configuration new problem appears. TableView is also scrollable in vertical and horizontal directions, which I don't want because padding to the right goes behind the view +23.5.

Comment: @ShadeToD - I don't think you'll get what you want that way... it sets the tableView's `scrollView` inset. You probably need to set the cell's `.contentView.layoutMargins`, using a positive value for both Left and Right insets.

Comment: I put this method inside cellForRowAt() and it works!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this either by setting the `.layoutMargins` on the cell's `contentView` (either in the cell class itself or in `cellForRowAt`:

```
cell.contentView.layoutMargins = .init(top: 0.0, left: 23.5, bottom: 0.0, right: 23.5)
```

or on the table view itself:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.layoutMargins = .init(top: 0.0, left: 23.5, bottom: 0.0, right: 23.5)
    // if you want the separator lines to follow the content width
    tableView.separatorInset = tableView.layoutMargins
}
```

Comment: This works as i wanted! Now my cells have paddings that match the design. Thank you

Comment: I need to add margins outside the TableViewCell. 
I tried doing `tableView.layoutMargins = .init(top: 0.0, left: 16.0, bottom: 0.0, right: 16/0)` and using `.directionalLayoutMargins` 
with 
`tableView.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = false` still to no avail. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

Add the constant while adding the constraints

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 20),
   tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: 20),
tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor)
])
```

Comment: As I mentioned earlier I want to do this without adding constant to constraints (I want that area to also be scrollable)

Comment: Okay then, can be done by adding the padding to cell content as well

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
override var frame: CGRect {
        get {
            return super.frame
        }
        set (newFrame) {
            var frame = newFrame
            frame.origin.x += 10
            frame.size.width -= 2 * 10
            super.frame = frame
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't think that playing with frames while using autolayout is a good solution.

Comment: This solution actually works for me, but I agree with @ShadeToD . Messing with the frame with an override just seems too hacky. There's got to be a cleaner way to add margins to the tableView's leading/trailing edge between the cell's contentView.